# Trying to run test case for react native component and getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined'

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have written a jest test to test a react-native component and I am getting the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:584:62)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:444:34)
```

Here is my test which is under the test folder. I have followed the docs implementation.

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import ForgotPassword from '../components/Forgotpassword';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';


it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<ForgotPassword />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

and my jest configuration is as follows

```
 "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "node_modules/?!(react-native|react-navigation)"
            
        ],
        "automock" : true,
        "verbose" : true
    },
```

Finally, my ForgotPassword component is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import { Button, Provider as PaperProvider, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import { styles } from '../styles/styleForgotpassword'


class Forgotpassword extends Component {

    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            error: '',
            success: '',
        }
    }

    onPress = () => {
        if (this.state.email === '') {
            this.setState({ error :'Must enter a valid email'});
            return;
        }
        
        auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.state.email).then(() => {
            this.setState({success : "Go to your email and reset your password.", error : ''});
        }).catch( error => {
            if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
                this.setState({error: "The user does not exist. Please enter the email you signed up with.", success: ''});
            } else if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email'){
                this.setState({error: "The email format is not correct. The email should look like example@domain.com", success: ''});
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <PaperProvider>
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.success}>{this.state.success}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.error}>{this.state.error}</Text>
            <TextInput
                label='Enter your Email address'
                mode='outlined'
                multiline
                blurOnSubmit
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                value={this.state.email}
            />
            <Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.onPress()}>
                <Text style={styles.buttontext}>
                    Send
                </Text>
            </Button>
                    <Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Signin')}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttontext}>
                            Sign In
                        </Text>
                    </Button>
            </ScrollView>
          </PaperProvider>
        )
    }

}

export default Forgotpassword;
```